# Components Loosing Focus in EXTJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a small big problem, I have a big form made up of small multiple reusable small forms that I use on other forms. The problem is If I fill in some information in any field and hit tab or select any field to insert data, the browser automatically moves to the top of the form. This action is random and not specific to any field. Any help would be appreciated. I am using EXTJS 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem of you form "autoscroll" is probably caused by validations of fields, i had the same problem using a form with a long scroll.

If you focus a field that can't be blank, and after you scroll down and focus an other field. Your focus will scroll you up because the validation is on blur.

Try to disable on all your fields [this property](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.form.field.Base.html#cfg-validateOnBlur) setting it to false. And use a

```
form.isValid()
```

to validate your form.

Comment: Thanks, Let me test it.